# Error al DesEncriptar una contraseña

Tags: android, android-studio, encriptación, hash, contraseña

Necesito ayuda, llevo días viendo como resolver este problema. Quiero desEncriptar un acontraseña pero cuando le pongo el código me sale como mensaje "ERROR: último bloque incompleto en el descifrado"

*************************************ERROR DE CÓDIGO**********************************************

```
W/System.err: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(BaseBlockCipher.java:1278)
W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2055)
W/System.err:     at com.holandes.delorean.usuario.view.LoginActivity.DesEncriptar(LoginActivity.java:390)
W/System.err:     at com.holandes.delorean.usuario.view.LoginActivity$2.afterTextChanged(LoginActivity.java:240)
W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:10805)
W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6407)
W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6227)
W/System.err:     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:121)
W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6179)
W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.setTransformationMethod(TextView.java:2661)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.material.textfield.PasswordToggleEndIconDelegate$4.onClick(PasswordToggleEndIconDelegate.java:102)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7441)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7418)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:835)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28676)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

---

Este es mi código:

***********************************CÓDIGO QUE UTILIZO*********************************************

```
 public SecretKeySpec GenerateKey (String password) throws  Exception
    {
        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256"); //512
        //md.update(salt.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] key = password.getBytes("UTF-8");
        key =  messageDigest.digest(key);
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key,"AES");
        return secretKeySpec;
    }
    public String DesEncriptar( String password)throws  Exception{
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = GenerateKey(password);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,secretKeySpec);
        byte[] DatosDesEncriptados = Base64.decode(password, Base64.DEFAULT);
        byte[] DesEncriptadoByte = cipher.doFinal(DatosDesEncriptados);
        String DatosDesString = new String(DesEncriptadoByte);
        //String DatosDesString = new String(DesEncriptadoByte, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        return DatosDesString;
    }
```

---

Esto es lo que quiero mostrar:

---

```
 Log.i("Desencriptado0" , DesEncriptar(Passname.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).toString()));
    Log.i("Desencriptado00" , DesEncriptar(edtClave.getText().toString()));
    Log.i("Desencriptado1" , DesEncriptar(controller.getUsuarioBean().getNuevoClave()));
    Log.i("Desencriptado2" , DesEncriptar(controller.getUsuarioBean().getNuevoClave().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).toString()));
    Log.i("Desencriptado3" , DesEncriptar(String.valueOf(controller.getUsuarioBean().getNuevoClave().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).toString())));
```

---

Comment: El problema que tienes es que al tratar de imprimir en el LogCat se muestra el error?

Comment: el error es: W/System.err: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption, no desencripta nada, no muestra nada. solo sale error :(